# Facet in ggplot giving differing results with same data format

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

```
day1 <- structure(list(shrub = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c","s", ""), class = "factor"), Plot_time = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,19L, 19L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), Lp = c(3, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 4, 4, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 0.5, 4.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 2, 1.5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 1.75, 1, 1.75, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3), day = c(1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("shrub", "Plot_time", "Lp", "day"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "37","38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48","49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71"), class = "data.frame")
#Make faceted ggplot boxplot comparing Lp by shrub treatment level
ggplot(data = day1,aes(x=(day1$shrub),y=(day1$Lp), colour = shrub))+geom_boxplot(size = 1)+scale_shape(solid = FALSE)+facet_grid(day~Plot_time)


#subset data that is not aligned in above plot and plot it separately
p14 = subset(day1, Plot_time == "19")
ggplot(data = p14,aes(x=(p14$shrub),y=(p14$Lp), colour = shrub))+geom_boxplot(size = 1)+scale_shape(solid = FALSE)
```

The facetted plot with three different boxplots in it comes out with strange alignment and three boxes in the "14" section, not 2. When I subset out only the time "14" and then make a boxplot, the plot appears to be centered, and has only the two boxes for the treatment levels.

I have 6 other data sets with the same format as this one, and when I run the facetted ggplot part of the code on them, all of the boxplots come out with centered boxes over the variable names, two to each plot. I have looked at str() for all the files as well as dput() and have not seen any difference in the data formats. I also re-entered all of the raw data and saved it to a new .csv file but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are referring to columns via `day1$shrub` inside of `aes()` which you should never, ever do. Nothing resembling that style of syntax ever occurs in any of the documentation or any (credible) ggplot2 guide in existance.

Try this:

```
ggplot(data = day1,aes(x=shrub,y=Lp, colour = shrub)) + 
  geom_boxplot(size = 1) + 
  scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + 
  facet_grid(day~Plot_time)
```